# Only make API call when data in Vuex store is "stale" or not present

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I am using Vuex for state management in my VueJS 2 application. In the `mounted` property of my component in question I dispatch an action...

```
mounted: function () {
  this.$store.dispatch({
    type: 'LOAD_LOCATION',
    id: this.$route.params.id
  });
}
```

...and this action uses axios to make an API call and get that location's details.

```
LOAD_LOCATION: function ({ commit }, { id }) {
  axios.get(`/api/locations/${id}`).then((response) => {
    commit('SET_LOCATION', { location: response.data })
  }, err => {
    console.log(err);
  });
}
```

The mutation looks like so:

```
SET_LOCATION: (state, { location }) => {
  state.locations.push(location);
}
```

This makes complete sense the first time this location is navigated to. However, let's say a user navigates to `/locations/5` then navigates elsewhere in the app and returns to `/locations/5` a few minutes later. Would it be a good idea to check for the location in `state.locations` and only make the API call if this location is not present? Or even better, to check the "staleness" of the location data and only make the API call to refresh the data after a certain period has passed?

Edit: Is there a pattern that is typically followed for these cases with Vuex? It seems to be a common case, but I'm not sure if jamming the logic to check for presence/staleness in the action is a solid approach.

Comment: Yes to both obviously

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Personally, I think it would be an excellent idea to do a check within the action to see if the data exists and set a timestamp when the data is received, then on subsequent calls it could determine if the data exits/is stale and act accordingly. That would speed up repeat visits and also save mobile users' data a bit.

Comment: In response to your edit, I haven't seen any common patterns for this use case around the internet. I do know, though, that a lot of React users are using react-query / swr which gives a lot of this nice functionality (see Option 4 in [this article](https://www.bitnative.com/2020/07/06/four-ways-to-fetch-data-in-react/))

And [here](https://markus.oberlehner.net/blog/stale-while-revalidate-data-fetching-composable-with-vue-3-composition-api/) is someone doing something similar in an ad hoc way for Vue 3 Composition API. Sorry I didn't find a Vue 2 / Vuex example.